# Ubuntu 14.04.2 unmet dependencies (similar for 14.04.3)

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I cannot install ros-indigo-desktop-full, because I get these errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
```

Tried aptitude, that gives me these conflicts:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfltk1.1-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev which is a virtual package.
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
                              Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 xserver-xorg-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libfltk1.3-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev which is a virtual package.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
```

Anyone has a suggestion for these errors? Should I try a new reinstall and hope for the best or is it a known error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14.04.2-unmet-dependencies-(similar-for-14.04.3)/) by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-23**:
This looks like a duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/202829/install-indigo-to-ubuntu-14042testing/

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
Using APT, I'm getting the same error as the OP, and the error's next line says: `ros-indigo-desktop-full depends on ros-indigo-desktop`
I'm running my Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro 15" Retina 2014.
@tfoote:  the details of that question are different.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I tried installing each of the dependencies mentioned but received the following in my terminal:
`libcheese-gtk23 is already the newest version. libcheese-gtk23 set to manually installed. 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I tried building from Source but after issuing the `rosdep install ...` command, it returned:

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
`E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libfltk1.1-dev] failed`

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
When I tried to install `libclutter-gtk-1.0-0` I get:
`libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 is already the newest version. 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-24**:
I believe the underlying issue is that the lts-utopic mesa drivers are conflicting with the standard mesa drivers. Which is the same issue as the other question. Can you see what information you can get from: sudo apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I need to post this in an answer field (not enough room in the comments section, or formatting options).

**Comment by [salto231](https://answers.ros.org/users/21705/salto231/) on 2015-02-24**:
I've encountered exactly the same problem with fresh installed ubuntu 14.04.2, and have done the requested command.

sudo apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes libcheese-gtk23
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

**Comment by [salto231](https://answers.ros.org/users/21705/salto231/) on 2015-02-24**:
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I tried installing Hydro from source but got the same error!  Hmmmm.
@tfoote:  Can you interpret the output I posted belew?  I having trouble determining what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I recently fixed this issue by installing the LTS enablement stack related `-dev` packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

**Edit:** I guess if this is the case then it would be a bug with Ubuntu. I.e. it tries to satisfy some dependency for some `-dev` package with one that conflicts with the already installed `-utopic` packages.

**Edit2:** I used something similar to upgrade to 14.04.3 HWE (the first set of packages is from the upgrade guide, the second are the -dev packages to prevent ros packages from uninstalling):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid           xserver-xorg-dev-lts-vivid mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid libxatracker-dev-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libgbm-dev-lts-vivid libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid
```

**Edit3:** For upgrading to 14.04.5 HWE (I skipped 14.04.4) the same approach seems to work on my machine:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial           xserver-xorg-dev-lts-xenial mesa-common-dev-lts-xenial libxatracker-dev-lts-xenial libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-xenial libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-xenial libgbm-dev-lts-xenial libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-xenial
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on 2015-02-24**:
Oh, it works. I just checked it on a VM, but dont think its gonna behave differently on my target machine.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-02-26**:
I have updated the ROS wiki with your fix http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation

Hopefully this will save any new users who are trying ROS on a fresh trusty install, until this dependency issue is resolved upstream.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-27**:
Thnx Demmeln.  I'm still going down the build from source path, and it did go a lot further, but I'm get a similar error still, but this time for Unity-Control Center:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies: unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going`

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-27**:
`to be installed Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-27**:
`ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev] failed`

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-27**:
Perhaps there is another package that needs to be added to your list?

**Comment by [Spyri](https://answers.ros.org/users/21799/spyri/) on 2015-03-06**:
I have been trying to make this work but I'm getting Unable to locate package, anyone knows how to solve this ?
I'm new to Linux, hope this isn't a dumb question.
Ty

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-11**:
I believe this is an issue upstream here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-lts-utopic/+bug/1424059

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-11**:
Also here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freeglut/+bug/1424466
And here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-03-11**:
Installing the libaries listed in the answer, I've been able to install Indigo Desktop-Full.  Everything seems to be working but Gazebo has problems with Namespaces. (I haven't used Gazebo much, so I'm not sure if this is actually a problem.)
However, I'm not able to build Indigo from source.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-03-13**:
with which error?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2015-04-21**:
FWIW: This got ROS running on my system, but the system failed to boot. I was able to recover by booting into recovery mode, dropping to root shell, manually setting up my internet connection, apt-get remove ros-* *-utopic, apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2015-10-04**:
The latter bunch of packages worked for me.

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-10-09**:
how about the Ubutun 14.04.3, do we need to do something

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-10-12**:
See my **Edit 2** above

**Comment by [Spyri](https://answers.ros.org/users/21799/spyri/) on 2015-11-18**:
I belive it really was a bug with my Ubuntu installation, the problem was solved by reinstalling Ubuntu.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-15**:
None of these worked for me.